# Lua pattern to stop when end of line

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I need to get help for a pattern in Lua stopping to read after a line break.
My code:

```
function getusers(file)
local list, close = {}
    local user, value = string.match(file,"(UserName=)(.*)")
    print(value)
    f:close()
end

f = assert(io.open('file2.ini', "r"))
local t = f:read("*all")
getusers(t)


--file2.ini--

user=a
UserName=Tom
Password=xyz
UserName=Jane
```

Output of script using file2.ini:

> Tom
>
> Password=xyz
>
> UserName=Jane

How to get the pattern to stop after it reaches the end of line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the pattern

```
"(UserName=)(.-)\n"
```

Note that besides the extra `\n`, the lazy modifier `-` is used instead of `*`.

---

As @lhf points out, make sure the file ends with a new line. I think you can append a `\n` to the string manually before matching.

Comment: Or use `"(UserName=)([^\n]*)"` or even `"(UserName=)(%w*)"`